# Help locate "snot" IPS/IDS testing tool?

Tags: penetration-test, ids, intrusion

It seems this great tool has been lost to internet backlog somewhere. I cannot locate it anywhere. The description of tools provided is

http://www.securityfocus.com/tools/category/112

If someone on the site uses this tool and have a copy can It be uploaded to any uploading site?

thanks

Comment: Huh. At first I thought you'd just misspelled "Snort". But no... Cool!

Comment: Closest reference I could find it a a filename: snot-0.92a.tar.gz from this pdf: http://www.iv2-technologies.com/HowToTestAnIPS.pdf no luck in finding a download as yet :(